# not returning the correct values while reading a file. "null" is returned instead

Tags: java, csv, object, null, readfile

I am reading from a csv file, and I have two objects. The first object is called Project, another one is called Location.

```
public class Project
{
    private String province;
    private String beneficiary;
    private String beneficiaryNum;
    private String assetClass;
    private String name;
    private String stage;
    Location location;

public Project(String pProvince, String pBeneficiary, String pBeneficiaryNum, String pAssetClass, String pName, String pStage, Location pLocation)
    {
        province = pProvince;
        beneficiary = pBeneficiary;
        beneficiaryNum = pBeneficiaryNum;
        assetClass = pAssetClass;
        name = pName;
        stage = pStage;
    }

public String toString()
    {
        return province + "\n" + beneficiary + "\n" + beneficiaryNum + "\n" + assetClass + "\n" + name + "\n" + stage + "\n" + location;
    }
...
```

```
public class Location
{
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String coordinateSystem;

public Location(double pLatitude, double pLongitude, String pCoordinateSystem)
    {
        latitude = pLatitude;
        longitude = pLongitude;
        coordinateSystem = pCoordinateSystem;
    }

public String toString()
    {
        return latitude + "\n" + longitude + "\n" + coordinateSystem;
    }
...
```

the issue is in the method processLine()

```
public static Project processLine(String pLine)
    {

        String[] lineSplit;
        lineSplit = pLine.split(",");
        
        //Converts the string in lineSplit[7] into a Double called 'lat'
        Double lat = Double.valueOf(lineSplit[7]);

        //Converts the string in lineSplit[8] into a Double calle 'lon'
        Double lon = Double.valueOf(lineSplit[8]);

        //Creates a new location object
        Location pLocation = new Location(lat, lon, lineSplit[9]);
        Project pProject = new Project(lineSplit[0],lineSplit[1],lineSplit[2],lineSplit[3],lineSplit[4],lineSplit[6],pLocation);

        return pProject;
        
    }
```

when I return pProject and try to print it, it prints out

```
//below is lineSplit[0,1,2,3,4,6]
Saskatchewan
All Nations Healing Hospital
9999
Health
Design and construction of a new community health facility.
Completed
//below is pLocation
null
```

I tried to isolate pLocation and print it, it returns

```
//pLocation
50.761877 //lat
-103.787043 //lon
GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS //lineSplit[9]
```

but when I try to print out pProject, with has pLocation as a field, it prints out null

How do I get it to print out pProject with pLocation in it?

I'm quite new to asking questions, so if I have stated anything in a wrong way, or haven't provided enough information please let me know, so I can provide info and improve :)

Comment: You're not assigning the `pLocation` parameter to anything in the `Project` header. Your IDE should have notified you of that fact.

Comment: You are getting the `Location` as a constructor argument of `Project`, but you are not assigning it to the `Location` inside the `Project`. You should do something like `this.location = pLocation;` inside the `Project` constructor.

Comment: Thank you I should have checked my constructors properly.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Project` constructor is missing the assignment for the parameter `pLocation`.

```
public Project(String pProvince, String pBeneficiary, String pBeneficiaryNum, String pAssetClass, String pName, String pStage, Location pLocation)
{
    province = pProvince;
    beneficiary = pBeneficiary;
    beneficiaryNum = pBeneficiaryNum;
    assetClass = pAssetClass;
    name = pName;
    stage = pStage;
    location = pLocation; // was missing
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped, I tried to find the problem for hours :(